# React router dom v5 history.push does not render new page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router-dom

I need to redirect user to their profile page after logging in and tried using history.push() inside Axios then. This is my code for the sign in form. I use the onClick button to get the email and password of user, and then redirect them to the new page, ClientProfile:

**SignIn.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Form, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function SignIn() {

    const history = useHistory();

  const [userEmail, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [userPassword, setPassword] = useState("");

//after onClick
  const signIn = () => {

//get user input
    Axios.post("http://localhost:8800/signIn", {
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userPassword: userPassword,
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        history.push('/clientprofile');
  })};

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here"  
                        onChange = {(event) => {
                          setEmail(event.target.value);
                        }}
                      />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Enter your password here" 
                    onChange = {(event) => {
                      setPassword(event.target.value);
                    }}
                    />
            </Form.Group>
            
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={ signIn }>
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default SignIn;
```

I define the route in **app.js** here:

```
import './App.css';
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
import About from './Components/About';
import Services from './Components/Services';
import Help from './Components/Help';
import SignIn from './Components/SignIn';
import ClientProfile from './Components/ClientProfile';
import { Switch, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar className="mainNav">
                <Container>
                        <Nav className="right-side me-auto">
                            <Nav.Link as = {NavLink} to = '/' className="text-white p-3">About Us</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link as = {NavLink} to = '/ourservices' className="text-white p-3">Our Services</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link as = {NavLink} to = '/help' className="text-white p-3">Help</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link as = {NavLink} to = '/signin' className="rounded-pill m-1 px-3 py-2 text-white signInBtn">Sign In</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <br/>
      
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path = "/"><About /></Route>
        <Route path = "/ourservices" ><Services /></Route>
        <Route path = "/help" ><Help /></Route>
        <Route path = "/signin"><SignIn /></Route>

//the route is being defined here
        <Route path = "/clientprofile"><ClientProfile/></Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

however, it does not render a new page and instead it stays on the same page, which is Sign In page. can anyone help me?

Comment: There can be a delay from isRedirect going from false to true. Either way, why change that state value if you’re intrnding to redirect anyway?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i tried that, and it is still the same result. anyway, updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are submitting the form but not preventing the default form action from occurring. This reloads the page before the POST request response can be handled and the UI redirected.

## Solution

Move the `onClick={signIn}` to the `Form` component and switch it to the `onSubmit` handler, and in the `signin` handler consume the `onSubmit` event object and prevent the default form action.

```
function SignIn() {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [userEmail, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [userPassword, setPassword] = useState("");

  //after onClick
  const signIn = (e) => { // <-- onSubmit event object
    e.preventDefault();   // <-- preventDefault
    // get user input
    Axios.post("http://localhost:8800/signIn", {
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userPassword: userPassword
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      history.push("/clientprofile");
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={signIn}> // <-- onSubmit event handler
      ...

      <Button variant="primary" type="submit"> // <-- remove onClick handler
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-v5-history-push-does-not-render-new-page]

Answer (score 0):

```
const signIn = () => {

//get user input
    Axios.post("http://localhost:8800/signIn", {
      userEmail: userEmail,
      userPassword: userPassword,
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setIsRedirect(true)

//redirect user
        if(isRedirect){
          history.push('/clientprofile');
        }
  })};
```

Here, inside the `.then` handler you are updating the state, and below it checking for the updated state.

**But React updates the state asynchronously.** So the updated state wont be available here.

Instead, you can use, `useEffect` hook and listen for updates to `isRedirect` state, and based on that you can perform your operations.

```
useEffect(()=>{

if(isRedirect){
    history.push('/clientprofile');
}

},[isRedirect,history])
```

Comment: It gives me this error:  `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history'`

Comment: Add `history`  to dependency array of `useEffect`

Comment: ah, that solves the missing dependency problem, but it still won't let me redirect to the new page. and when I check the console, no error shown but `consoloe.log(res)` does not return anything as well. Could it be a problem inside the Axios then?

Comment: Might be the case, you've to check whether your Axios is fetching properly or not

Answer (score 0):

- For the version of `react router dom` less than `6.^`

You can use `useHistory()` hook like your code is showing

- For the latest version of `react router dom` greater than `6.^`

You can use `useNavigate()` hook like this.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const signIn = () => {
  ....

  let navigate = useNavigate();

         .....
         ......

      navigate('/clientprofile');
    
    .....

  }
```

So please check your react-router-dom version in package.json file and do accordingly.

Comment: OP is using `Switch` component and `useHistory` hook without any build errors, it's likely safe to assume usage of RRDv5 here.